# How to access a private variable that is a 2D array with getter function

Tags: c++

Im making a chess game and I have a board class that looks something like this:

```
class Board {
private:
    Tile tiles[8][8];
public:
    Tile getTiles() {
        return **tiles;
    }
}
```

where Tile is another class with its member that I want to access.

The problem is that I cant really do something like:

```
void foo() {
    Board board;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board.getTiles()[i][j].getPosition(); //visibly makes no sense and gives an error
        }
    }
}
```

How should I access this array and is it even possible?

Comment: Does this really need to be 2D? 1D with emulation is often less fuss.

Comment: Turn on more compiler warnings. `return **tiles` is not possible. That's an array of arrays, not an array of pointers. That's also a mismatched return type.

Comment: @tadman I guess that would be one way to go around it but Im genuinly interested what the procedure is in this case.

Comment: `getTiles` returns `**tiles`, which is the top left tile. If you want to retrieve the whole table, just use `return tiles;`. Also change the function's return type to reflect that.

Comment: Why not just have a `getTile(int row, int column)`? Your board is already a container of tiles, give it a higher level interface. No need to return implementation details.

Comment: I'd use `std::vector` and then `const std::vector<Tile>& getTiles() const { return tiles; }` where `std::vector<Tile> tiles` is the internal structure.

Comment: That really should be called `const Tile& getTile(const int row, const int col) const` if your intent is to use it that way. Key here being *use `const`* and *use references*.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel great answer, will probably go with that.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes can I ask how to change the return type as Im not entirely sure. The return **tiles was just an assumption.

Comment: Once you have the above issues worked out, consider how `private` the array is when you're going to hand a pointer to it to anyone who asks.

Comment: @user4581301 thats a very good point but Im just working with the bare minimum we have been taught at school (i.e. getter and setter functions). I really dont know much about proper class usage and good practice.

Comment: @HinterinoSalterino You just declare the function with the desired return type: `Tile** getTiles() { ... }` (also consider adding appropriate `const` modifiers later).

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes I wouldn't add `const` "later", const correctness is important.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Ive tried this for a fact but its giving me an error: `return value type does not match the function type`. And this is after Ive removed the ** from `return **tiles`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Of course, but OP has explicitely stated they are new to this, so they should focus on making it work at all, then we can worry about foolproofing (I should have specified, "later" means "immediately after the main thing works"). That being said, I agree with your note.

Comment: @HinterinoSalterino You have to both change the return type (to `Tile**`) *and* the return value (to `tiles`), both at once. Then it should work.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes You cannot convert `Tiles[8][8]` to `Tiles**`. Apologies it I've missed something in the comments above.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes that is just what I did (Im also fascinated it doesnt work). Lemme throw it here real quick its a small function anyway: `Tile** getTiles() { return tiles; }`

Comment: I agree with @john :)

Comment: There is no conversion from a 2D array like `Tiles[8][8]` to a double pointer like `Tiles**`. You've been badly advised.

Comment: Thats good to know.

Comment: @HinterinoSalterino Simplest answer (not necessarily the best) is to add row and column parameters to your function, as already mentioned above.

Comment: Right... Sorry for being a mess. The best way seems to be really retrieving an individual tile. Appologies.

Comment: As an added bonus, access tile-by-tile removes most of the concerns I raised above. Etienne's answer returning by value means that while an outside can see the `Tile`s, they cannot break the `Tile`. All they have available is a copy of the `Tile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a Board is a collection of tiles. From a high level perspective, that's all it does. That it's stored as a 1D array, a 2D array, an hash map or a self balancing binary tree does not matter for the user. All that matters is that there are tiles in it.

So, you should instead do it that way:

```
Tile getTile(int row, int column) const {
    return tiles[row][column];
}
```

Alternatively, return by reference to avoid a copy and/or allow external modifications, but don't forget about const correctness:

```
const Tile& getTile(int row, int column) const;
Tile& getTile(int row, int column);
```

Then, if you change your mind and decide to go for a one dimentional array, well, it's easy!

```
Tile getTile(int row, int column) const {
    return tiles[row * 8 + column];
}
```

The external API does not change, no user code breaks, and everyone can go on with their lives.

Comment: Returning by reference, `Tile & getTile(int row, int column) { return tiles[row][column]; }`, may also be useful if there's a requirement to edit the accessed `Tile`

Comment: @user4581301 I have updated the answer to take that into account (and also mention `const`).